# Pandas DataFrame Display in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I want to make my display tables bigger so users can see the tables better when that are used in conjunction with Jupyter RISE (slide shows).

How do I do that? 
I don't need to show more columns, but rather I want the table to fill up the whole width of the Jupyter RISE slide.

Any idea on how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If `df` is a `pandas.DataFrame` object.

You can do:

`df.style.set_properties(**{'max-width': '200px', 'font-size': '15pt'})`